# Matplotlib роняет ipython kernel в jupyter notebook, что делать?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

Создал свое окружение в conda, установил python==3.8, пакеты numpy, pandas, matplotlib, установил jupyter notebook. Открыл тетрадь с построением графика ядро упало. Версии все последние. Пытаюсь вернуться к старым версиям, которые используются в других рабочих окружениях, проблема остается. Как быть?

Вот лог сервера:
C:\Users\Popov.conda\envs\compvis\lib\json\encoder.py:257: UserWarning: date_default is deprecated since jupyter_client 7.0.0. Use jupyter_client.jsonutil.json_default.
return _iterencode(o, 0)
[W 12:16:54.963 NotebookApp] 404 GET /nbextensions/nbextensions_configurator/tree_tab/main.js?v=20211105121642 (127.0.0.1) 16.000000ms referer=http://localhost:8888/tree
[W 12:17:11.721 NotebookApp] Notebook task1.ipynb is not trusted
ERROR:asyncio:Exception in callback <TaskWakeupMethWrapper object at 0x0000029309CAC0D0>(<Future finis...igin\r\n\r\n'>)
handle: <Handle <TaskWakeupMethWrapper object at 0x0000029309CAC0D0>(<Future finis...igin\r\n\r\n'>)>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Popov.conda\envs\compvis\lib\asyncio\events.py", line 81, in _run
self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
RuntimeError: Cannot enter into task <Task pending name='Task-27' coro=<HTTP1ServerConnection._server_request_loop() running at C:\Users\Popov.conda\envs\compvis\lib\site-packages\tornado\http1connection.py:823> wait_for=<Future finished result=b'GET /api/co...rigin\r\n\r\n'> cb=[IOLoop.add_future..() at C:\Users\Popov.conda\envs\compvis\lib\site-packages\tornado\ioloop.py:688]> while another task <Task pending name='Task-2' coro=<KernelManager._async_start_kernel() running at C:\Users\Popov.conda\envs\compvis\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\manager.py:335>> is being executed.
ERROR:asyncio:Exception in callback <TaskWakeupMethWrapper object at 0x00000293096010D0>(<Future finis...igin\r\n\r\n'>)
handle: <Handle <TaskWakeupMethWrapper object at 0x00000293096010D0>(<Future finis...igin\r\n\r\n'>)>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Popov.conda\envs\compvis\lib\asyncio\events.py", line 81, in _run
self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
RuntimeError: Cannot enter into task <Task pending name='Task-32' coro=<HTTP1ServerConnection._server_request_loop() running at C:\Users\Popov.conda\envs\compvis\lib\site-packages\tornado\http1connection.py:823> wait_for=<Future finished result=b'GET /nbexte...rigin\r\n\r\n'> cb=[IOLoop.add_future..() at C:\Users\Popov.conda\envs\compvis\lib\site-packages\tornado\ioloop.py:688]> while another task <Task pending name='Task-2' coro=<KernelManager._async_start_kernel() running at C:\Users\Popov.conda\envs\compvis\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\manager.py:336>> is being executed.
[I 12:17:12.226 NotebookApp] Kernel started: 2d6d2f77-c61e-40e7-bb05-c644f78d4185, name: python3
[W 12:17:12.364 NotebookApp] 404 GET /static/skill.js?v=20211105121642 (127.0.0.1) 5.010000ms referer=http://localhost:8888/notebooks/task1.ipynb
[I 12:17:24.193 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (1/5), keep random ports
WARNING:root:kernel 2d6d2f77-c61e-40e7-bb05-c644f78d4185 restarted
[I 12:18:52.931 NotebookApp] Saving file at /task1.ipynb
[W 12:18:52.932 NotebookApp] Notebook task1.ipynb is not trusted
[I 12:18:52.990 NotebookApp] Starting buffering for 2d6d2f77-c61e-40e7-bb05-c644f78d4185:5c5127582c3f48abacd09a7bcb166d4d
[I 12:18:58.813 NotebookApp] Kernel shutdown: 2d6d2f77-c61e-40e7-bb05-c644f78d4185

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: На любом графике падает? А то может вы что-то слишком большое рисуете. Опять же лог ведь есть, ядро когда падает что-то пишет в него. Что там написано, какая причина падения? И не все версии пакетов совместимы между собой.

Comment: Падает на любом вызове plot, даже на элементарном. Проблема эта возникла буквально неделю назад, две недели назад ставил все на разных компах все летало, версии пакетов были правда другие.

Answer (score 0):

**Решение**
Проблема снимается даунгрейдом пакета freetype. Пакет freetype это обертка над библиотекой С, которая качественно отображает шрифт. Подробнее [описано тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69786885/after-conda-update-python-kernel-crashes-when-matplotlib-is-used).